# Why is my Friedman posthoc test said to be "true" with a p value of 0.06?

Tags: r, friedman-test

I used the function `friedman.test` to test for differences between multiple conditions and then used `friedmanmc` as a posthoc test. As a result, three comparisons are said to be "true" about the statistical significance, however with one p-value being 0.06.

Here are the crucial parts of my results:

```
alpha: 0.05 
Comparisons
                                obs.dif critical.dif stat.signif    p.value
Control-Novelty                    29.5     29.05699        TRUE 0.06054204
Control-Safety                     33.0     29.05699        TRUE 0.01800952
Control-SafetyNovelty1x            34.0     29.05699        TRUE 0.01246575
```

Why is this the case? Is it significant or not?